# Hole inside my one inch steak

Tags: steak

Last night at dinner I ordered a 6 once steak, cooked medium. They brought it back to me, red/raw on the inside. The took it away, brought me another steak, I cut into it like the mid center section of the steak, as I cut it, there was a HOLE inside the steak and it was black inside the hole, what the heck was that???

Comment: When you say 'hole' do you mean the steak was punctured? Or do you mean you found a 'spherical gap' inside the steak? How big was it?

Comment: Did you return the second steak? I've never seen anything like that and would find it disturbing. I've heard of restaurants where kitchen employees and/or service staff take revenge on diners who return items, no matter how valid the reason.

Comment: Obviously, it was a black hole. Consensus up until now was that you won't survive an encounter with a black hole, new research will be needed ;)

Comment: I second @ElmerCat.  When I worked in restaurants, I saw some some unpleasant things done to food returned to the kitchen.  I'm very reluctant to send anything back. I'll just try and get it removed from the check.

Comment: Could it be blood that congealed and was trapped in between layers of tissue that then turned black when cooked?

Comment: Upvote, because I'm super curious. But you would do well to provide a more thorough description of the location and dimension of the hole. Was it pierced through the outside, like the probe thermometer answer suggests? Or was it a cavity that was only visible in a cross section?

Comment: A picture would be really awesome for helping us figure out the mystery

Comment: Sounds like the waiter got shot at returning the steak, steak got hit instead...

Answer (score 0):

In a busy restaurant, steak is generally cooked by feel.  Since you returned this steak as under cooked for your preference, the cook probably measured the temperature with a probe thermometer.  The hole was probably a puncture, where the cook inserted a probe thermometer to ensure your returned steak was cooked accurately.

Comment: A thermometer wouldn't likely change the color of the steak to black, though...

Comment: @catija, not a deal breaker for my hypothesis.  Something could have been on the probe, some char could have been poked into the meat...not having seen it, and with only the information provided, my theory is still plausible.